# Mirroring to start Symmetry - object doesnt flip

Tags: mirror

I'll keep it simple, unlike Max or other programs, Blender isn't flipping the object mirrored. Say for instance I have a 3d shape like this symbol "<" and I mirror it in Max over the center X axis, the result would be this pair of shapes " <    > "

So far in Blender all I can get is this " <    < " which is the same shape, just on the opposite coords of the axis. This is useless for setting up symmetry. How can I properly mirror an object without having to flip it manually?

Comment: What process did you use to mirror your geometry ?

Comment: Ah, I failed to mention that I was mirroring a Bezier Curve with a Geomery Bevel to Bezier Circle modifier applied to it. Perhaps that has something to do with why it doesn't appear to be behaving normally.

As to how I did my mirror, I moved the 3d cursor and pivot to 0,0,0, > clicked on the Beveled BezierCurve > applied mirror from modifier panel > hit Axis X (then Y for experimental purposes)  
Anyway, here's whats going on, I want the shape where the Orange outline is so I can start hair.  https://imgur.com/LlSh9xW

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways to mirror an object in Blender:

1. **Mirror Mofifier**

This is an undestructive method to mirror your object with the most control. Go to the object's modifier panel and add a mirror modifier:

(Blender doc: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/generate/mirror.html)

[image: Mirror Modifier]

2. **Edit Mode Mirror**

Go into Edit Mode, and press 'CTRL+M' or in the menu go Mesh>Mirror>Desired Axis

This is a destructive but direct solution to mirror your object.

(Blender doc: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/editing/transform/mirror.html#mirror)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, however neither method properly places or flips my object, which is a bezier curve with bevel on it. Perhaps my prior post to the person above will clarify in greater detail?

Answer (score 0):

I repeated making a beveled curve and now it mirrors properly.

I think what might have corrupted the other curve is when I tried to edit the positioning of the bezier curve in Object Mode. It appears to move the transform gizmo's location while doing nothing to the curve. Reasons unknown. Thanks anyway for trying to help.

Comment: When you use a curve to bevel another curve, the origin position of each object is very important. To avoid any confusion try to have both at the same point in space.